# Bluetooth mouse not pairing

Tags: networking, dual-boot, drivers, mouse, bluetooth

I'm trying to connect an honor Bluetooth mouse to my honor magicbook on its Ubuntu installation. It works perfectly on windows, but I can't connect it to ubuntu. I can connect other devices, but not the mouse. It appears doubled in both gnome and bluetoothctl, with the MACs being the same but one ending in 94 and one in 95. Help? It appears as a single device in Windows

Ubuntu 20 latest version
Honor Magicbook
Bluetooth/WLAN adapter Realtek 8822CE Wireless LAN 802.11ac PCI-E NIC

Comment: Goto "additional Drivers" in the start menu. Does the driver show up there?